# "Someone was refreshingly honest when [...]": is the adverb an obfuscated adjunct?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, adverb-placement, adjuncts

Please consider the [following](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23380):

> (1) My colleague was *refreshingly honest* when I asked her for feedback.
>   (2) It was refreshing to see my colleague being honest when I asked her
>   for feedback.
>   (3) He is amazingly handsome.
>   (4) [Amazingly(,)] he is handsome [(,)amazingly].

I don't understand in what way [*refreshingly*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/refreshingly?s=t) modifies *honest*? Had it been *for once* instead, how would that qualify at modifying only the adjective and not the whole construct or sentence altogether? Compare the position, and function, of *(it was) refreshing + inf.* in (2); doesn't it mean the same thing? With *amazingly* and a simpler phrase, the position seemingly matches the function, as in the degree with (3) or, externally (as an adjunct or something else), the unexpected turn of events with (4). What I gather from (1) is that the speaker thinks this colleague or other coworkers generally might not have always been so forthcoming in the past, and since she is now in this very instance, it feels like something *pleasingly fresh or different* in context; is it more generic? Using (the conjunction?) *when* and the complement makes it even more about the quality of a moment in time based on the speaker's contrasting past experience, as opposed to some variation on the colleague being honest in whatever way.

---

Is that just a more complex type of modifier, not unlike what a (partial) restrictive focusing modifier is (a bit like *only* etc.) but which still does something comparable to what degree/manner adverbs do, or does it function at the sentence level, like what I understand a VP-oriented adjunct of sorts does? In so many words I feel that in (1) there is like a type mismatch, and the adverb rather seems to be functioning independently as an adjunct to the verb phrase, similar to what *it was refreshing* essentially yields in (2). And this doesn't feel all too different from something like *fortunately* at the beginning of a sentence, and this wouldn't be modifying the adjective *honest* (that I know of).

---

- What are the different phrases in (1), what is the exact function and scope of the adverb *refreshingly* and what type of modifier would it be?
- Can (1) be construed like an active reordering of (2) which is more positional than functional and which eludes (adjectival) phrase scope as an adjunct would; can we tell without further context (subtext, commas, or appearing at the beginning of the sentence)? Does the scope vary from a category of modifier to the next in an adjectival phrase? Is this some hybrid or it simply an adverb of manner, about a new sensation in general (as opposed to having the potential to actually refresh in a figurative way), yet detached from any specific reference to the personal experience of the speaker or moment in time, and therefore well suited for modifying the adjective and being limited in scope to that phrase?

Comment: This may help you [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refreshingly)

Comment: My eyes are glazing over because you have too much stuff in your questions. I would simplify. There is a basic ambiguity in the sentence but it does not derive from /refreshingly honest/. The two readings are: Others are not usually honest OR: She was not always honest at other times. There is no way given just this context to decide which is intended.

Comment: *Refreshingly honest* here doesn't mean that the author's colleague is usually dishonest. It could just mean that people are usually reluctant to give the author direct criticism, so when the colleague was more direct, the author appreciated it.

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté Your sentences 1 and 2 mean essential same thing. /refreshingly honest/ and /It was refreshing to/: both reveal the speaker's attitude. And /It is amazing to see how handsome he is/ is also essentially similar to /He is amazingly handsome/. It + present continuous also reveals the speaker's attitude. But putting adverbs in either case at the head of the sentence with a comma changes the meaning completely. If you put the adverb at the beginning of the sentence, the meaning is different. refreshingly honest is no different from any adverb + adjective pair.

Comment: I now see a logical fallacy in the time line of sentence 1 that might explain why this particular use of “adverb+adjective+when” makes my brain buzz too. Her refreshing honesty couldn’t have appeared when the request was made, but only when she provided it. There’s less buzzing in my brain w/“She was [being] refreshingly honest when responding/when she responded to my request for feedback” or “Refreshingly, she was [brutally] honest when providing feedback. Also, “She was very proud when I asked her for feedback” doesn’t buzz 'cause her pride could have logically surfaced at just being asked.

Comment: I really do not think that a time line has anything to do with it. One could say: She is a refreshingly honest person. Same meaning re refreshingly honest. Nothing will change what "refreshingly honest" means regardless of whether the rest of the sentence is not very clear about when the person was being refreshingly honest.

Comment: Anyway, with this “defect” out of the way it’s easier for me to hazard an uneducated guess that “refreshingly” here is serving as an [“Evaluation {Stance} Adverb”](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/stanceadverbs.html#adveval) & that since “refreshingly” has only one basic meaning (“serving to refresh” & “pleasantly fresh & different” are close,imo) its position in the sentence would not change its meaning (unlike “amazingly” which has two distinct meanings [see also “exceptionally” which also has two distinct meanings, one of which would almost mean “refreshingly” when used at sentence’s start]).

Comment: /He is amazingly handsome/ and /Amazingly, he is handsome/. Amazingly means the same thing in both but they qualify (modify) different things. I really do not know what you mean by defect.

Comment: @Lambie It’s probably just me, but when [“amazingly”](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amazingly) begins a sentence I usually take it to mean sense #1 ("In a way that causes great surprise or wonder"=”Amazingly/surprisingly [enough] [because/in spite of how ugly her brother is], she is beautiful) and sense #1.2 ("very; extremely") when it’s intensifying an adjective=”She is amazingly/very/extremely beautiful.” .... to be continued...1/2

Comment: @Lambie ...2/2... As for the “defect,” that's referring to the “[time-line] logical fallacy” I mentioned a few comments above. I put it in scare quotes in deference to your having politely pooh-poohed it.(Although irrelevant here, I also think your suggested translation on the French site contains this same “defect” (I would have said “Le feedback que j'ai **eu/reçu de** ma collègue…” instead of  “ … **demandé à** ….”).  Although such defects, if any, might not have anything to do with anything either here or there, they can muddy the waters and make parsing more difficult (at least for me).

Comment: @Papa Poule Do you want my real opinion on this whole thing? I think there is language interference. In this case, from French. It is very annoying at times when a particular word calls for an entire workaround in the other language. This is the case with refreshing here in English. It's not easy to put into French.  That does not mean that its existence in the source language is weird.This interference thing can go the other way, too. Par ailleurs, on peut très bien demandé un feedback à une collègue....

Comment: @Lambie You're on a learners site and I'm not a native speaker so of course I'm coming from somewhere but you're quite safe and I couldn't care less about translating, it was just a(n) (missed) opportunity to explore grammar, especially with respect to **stance adverbs** (thks Papa Poule), as opposed to manner etc.. Is the position of the former relevant to the meaning, as opposed to... ; is it possible to have a stance use independent of a manner use (concurrent); then context: does time, clause sequence, or phrase etc. construction, impact any of this? With _refreshingly_, _amazingly_....

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté I have no idea what you mean by: Is it possible to have a stance use independent of a manner use (concurrent). You either have one or the other. Here the adverb is with the adjective. It modifies the adjective. Not a truth statement or belief thing like an adverbial adjunct or stance adverb.

Comment: I am just saying that **maybe** since you are not a native speaker, this idea of refreshing which is not rafraîchissant in French except in cases of stuff like drinks or swimming or breezes, is "pas évident". But for an English speaker it works like so many other adverbs + adjectives. People and situations in French cannot be called "refreshing" but in English they can. And this adverb refreshingly is not a stance adverb really. It's like any other adverb of degree/manner: amazingly handsome, refreshingly honest, brutally honest, unnervingly honest all just reveal the speaker's attitude.

Comment: @Lambie Helpful, thks. I didn't mean concurrent as in at the same time but rather in different contexts for the same adverb i.e refreshingly as stance, refreshingly as manner, refreshingly as stance at the head of the sentence, or not, etc. It's possible I see also a more literal use (the potential to refresh) as another option which adds confusion to the cases. Maybe when refreshingly is split between the subjective part (pleasingly) and the attribute (new-fresh) I read it differently etc. I'm going to think further about sth like _fortunately, my colleague's purse is refreshingly blue_.

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté - Fortunately, my colleague's mood is intrinsically bright. or Unfortunately, my colleague's attitude is dipsomaniacally skewed. [not on google, ha ha]. The party drinks were refreshingly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is *surprisingly* simple.

Who is surprised?  Why, everyone, anyone, and nobody.

The answer is so simple that it would surprise *a person*.  That is the nature of its simplicity.

> That man is frighteningly stupid but he will be heading the
>   department.

Answer (score 2):

An adverb can modify a verb, adjective or adverb.  Consider placement and what word is being modified.  The VERY fat man ran TOO QUICKLY. Obfuscated adjunct means the adverb subtly alters the meaning of the statement.  He was TOO smart. This makes a usually positive word appear negative. Honest is a positive trait. BRUTALLY honest modifies the meaning to imply a cruel statement. REFRESHINGLY honest implies that it is unusual to have people speak with candour and be straightforward instead of painstakingly polite and pleasant. PAINSTAKINGLY polite implies a degree of phoniness or fear of upsetting other people.

An obfuscated adjunct is similar to a scoping word that alters or refines the meaning of a statement. "VIRTUALLY all people like puppies" prevents making a generalisation or bold statement that could be challenged. Adverbs can dramatically alter a statement and imply a positive or negative association.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand in what way refreshingly modifies honest?

It doesn't.  It modifies *was*.

Consider this example with a different verb:

> My colleague read refreshingly well

The manner/way/method in which she read was refreshing, i.e. had the attribute 'refreshing.'

So...

> My colleague was refreshingly honest when I asked her for feedback.

She was honest, the manner/way/method in which she was honest had the attribute 'refreshing'.  Therefore, *refreshingly*.

It may seem weird to answer the question *how* (which indicates an adverb) for the verb *to be* but it's possible.

Comment: This isn't true at all. In your second example, *well* is how your colleague read. How well? Refreshingly well. *Refreshingly* modifies *well*. The same is true for the first example. The honesty was refreshing, not the *being*.

Comment: Thanks. This is what VP-oriented means imho, because it links the adverb to the verb or entire verb phrase and not the the adjectival phrase (_refreshingly honest_). But I think you mean it as a description of how to read the sentence and not as having any direct impact on the meaning. It that all because _refreshingly_ "means" another subjective adverb (_pleasingly_) + _new/fresh_, and whether you read its subjective aspect (_pleasingly_ for me) through the verb, or the attribute (_new/fresh_) along the adjective, you end up with the same result or meaning (_pleasingly new/fresh_)?